# Creating Ruby ActiveRecord objects with associations

Tags: ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have Persons and Teams that have Addresses (polymorphic association)

I need to create persons and addresses separately in code:

person = Person.new

address = Address.new

and then link them together using something like:

`person.addressable.push(address)`

finally, do:

`person.save!`

This however gives a You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.has_key?

Could someone let me know what I need to be doing? There is little code on google that demoes any of this and all I could find was the API reference

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - I had overridden initialize in the Address class. Figured out it was the dumbest thing to do :-(